# Android : How to know the number of virtual screens

Tags: android, launcher, virtual-screen

I need to know the number of virtual screens of the desktop but I don't know where I can find this information.

I think I need to access to the launcher but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Not all home screen applications have "virtual screen of the desktop". Applications should neither know nor care what the home screen looks or behaves like.

Comment: The reason one might care is if you are a live wallpaper whose view changes based on the number of virtual screens and the current virtual screen position.